# UNION operator with QueryBuilder

Tags: java, android, ormlite, query-builder

I want to create a `SELECT` statement, which is a union of two sub-queries.
Is there any way in ORMLite to create the two queries with `QueryBuilder`, and then concatenate them and create a `UNION` like this with a third `QueryBuilder`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
        FIRST SELECT
        UNION 
        SECOND SELECT)
    WHERE isdefault = 0 ORDER BY someRow;
```

`someRow` also changes dinamically. As for as i know `QueryBuilder` does not
support `UNION` directly, so somehow i should inject the concatenated union into
its statement. As the result i want to get a `List<MyObject>` like `QueryBuilder.query()` returns it.

Comment: I don't quite understand how ORMLite can construct an object from a UNION column list. Can you explain how it could work?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Maybe my question is not clear for you because i'm not using `UNION` _properly_? My query is the union of two `SELECT` subqueries on the _same_ table. In this case it is clear that ORMLite could create the objects. Here is my select BTW: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Cards WHERE (GroupId < 0 AND IsDefault = 0 )  UNION SELECT * FROM Cards WHERE GroupId >= 0 GROUP BY GroupId  ) ORDER BY Title`.

Comment: I managed to create a workaround: i wrote a query which uses `IN`, and this can be built with `QueryBuilder`. But i think it would still nice if `QueryBuilder` would support `IN` statements. :)