# ForeignCollection auto load with queryRaw()

Tags: java, android, ormlite, foreign-collection

I have a `Card` class, which has an eager `ForeignCollection` in it. I have to query for the instances of this class with a `Dao.queryRaw()`, because my `SELECT` is too complicated to be built with a simple `QueryBuilder` (see my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099871/union-operator-with-querybuilder)). This is how i query and build my objects with `RawRowMapper`:

```
GenericRawResults<String[]> rawResults = getCardDao().queryRaw(statement);
List<Card> results = new ArrayList<Card>();

for (String[] row : rawResults) {
    results.add(getCardDao().getRawRowMapper().mapRow(rawResults.getColumnNames(), row));
}

rawResults.close();
```

Unfortunately when i try to get the `ForeignCollection` on my objects, it returns null. If i query the objects with a simple `Dao.queryForFirst`, the `ForeignCollection` is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem today.
My solution has been to call something as

```
dao.refresh(<Card object>)
```

for every object returned by the queryRaw function (and accumulated into "results" list).
This do the trick for me, reloading objects from DB with filled foreign collection.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed it is a good solution, i just checked it. This is quiet an old question, thanks again for sharing your answer.

Comment: I know it is not an optimized solution (for every refresh there will be a query to "reload" the object's status). I'm wondering if there is a better solution to manage this problem for big query results...

Comment: If you are really interested at this case, you should ask a question in the [ORMLite maling list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ormlite-user). It seems that the library author is more active on that than on SO.